# Why does a "Hidden Network" affect my Wifi?

Tags: networking

My laptop keeps showing this "Hidden Network", which pops up at random times throughout the day. It doesn't seem to be there at night, although I may just be asleep when it does. When it is there, my Wifi always becomes extremely slow and there is no way to fix it. I have no idea why it is there and how to get rid of it. It is also not only on my laptop, but also every other device in the house. It's honestly starting to creep me out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A "hidden network" is just a normal WLAN access point that is configured not to broadcast its SSID.

If your Wifi gets slow, it's the same problem as with any other WLAN on the same frequency, hidden or not: If it occupies the same frequency, it may cause collisions between your transmissions and the transmissions on that network.

So check the frequency of the network, move your own network to a different frequency with enough separation, if you can. Keep in mind that 2.4 GHz Wifi networks use multiple adjacent channels.

As for why it is there: Any computer-like device can act as a WLAN access point, hidden or not. Maybe it's one of your own devices which is misconfigured or running some software that does that. Maybe it's one of your neighbour's devices. You can try to triangulate it by measuring signal strength from various locations, but it's one of your neighbour's devices, there's little you can do about it (except talking to your neighbour).